# Indexing NAS with "mdutil -i on" with Sierra not working anymore

Tags: spotlight, macos, nas

I used to index my NAS with the command line `mdutil -i on`. Ok, I know it's not perfect, but it worked for me.

But since I updated to macOS Sierra it's not working anymore.
If I type `mdutil /Volumes/name -i on` I just get the feedback `Indexing disabled.` It doesn't matter if I use SMB or AFP (SMB was always working for me).

Maybe this information is helpful for a solution, if I `mdutil /Volumes/name -E` I get the feedback: `mdutil disabling Spotlight: /Volumes/archiv -> kMDConfigSearchLevelFSSearchOnly. Indexing disabled.`

Does anyone has any solution?

Comment: Presumably `mdutil -s -a -v` shows indexing and searched disabled for the NAS volume? Also does `man mdutil` show any restrictions on enabling using `-i` that might be new to Sierra? (I'm on El Capitan and it doesn't list anything, but it could have changed.)

Comment: mdutil -s -a -v just shows "indexing disabled" for the  (the share). Before i was on Yosemite and it worked fine.

Comment: I came here looking for a solution and found your question. It seems to be a problem with Sierra+ itself, since Yosemite was working perfectly fine for me as well. :\

Comment: Also looking for a solution to this.. If your NAS is one you've built yourself (a linux box) then you can apparently compile Samba with spotlight support using `tracker` but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Same here since Sierra.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this support page](https://care.qumulo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008514788-Mac-OS-X-Spotlight-Search-and-Qumulo) by [Qumulo](https://qumulo.com/about/what-we-believe/), there is a fix, which basically consists of the following:

> To fix this issue, create the following directory as root:
>
> `sudo mkdir -p /private/var/db/Spotlight-V100/Volumes/`
>
> And then re-enable Spotlight indexing of that Volume:
>
> `sudo mdutil -i on /Volumes/name_of_your_volume`

I haven't tried it myself, but I thought it's worthwile to mention it here.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting Index disabled after each run of `mdutil -i` on a SMB volume. Creating that directory solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a Synology NAS (DSM7) on macOS Monterey.

It seems that Spotlight and the Synology's built-in 'File Indexing' are incompatible.

The solution was:

1. Open `Universal Search` on the Synology. Click the Preferences cog and remove all indexed folders.
2. Disconnect and reconnect the volume from your Mac.
3. `sudo mdutil -i on /path/to/volume`
4. Wait for indexing. No need to do the `mdutil -E`, it'll do itself. (I can immediately hear the drives working.)